# python: validating function parameters

Tags: python, coding-style, python-3.x

I need to make sure all the named parameters were passed to a method (I don't want any defaults). Is the following the best way to enforce it?

```
class X:
  def func(self, **kwargs):
    if set(kwargs.keys() != ('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'):
      raise ArgException(kwargs)
```

Comment: Be sure that the exception you're raising is a subclass of TypeError.  Why are you using kwargs at all if you want to do this?  Just specify the variables normally.

Comment: Bad, bad design.  Use `def func( self, arg1, arg2, arg3 )`.

Comment: @S Lott I would use what you suggest, but then I keep making mistakes in the order of the arguments. @Glenn Maynard I was using named parameters just to avoid mistakes in the order (I have 3-6 arguments in many of my functions). Not good?

Comment: OMG I didn't know that I can use keyword arguments even when the function is defined as `def func(self, a, b, c)`... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 2.x, Hugh's answer (i.e. just use named positional arguments) is your best bet.

For Python 3.x, you also have the option of *requiring* the use of keyword arguments (rather than merely allowing it) as follows:

```
class X(object):
    def func(self, *, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class X(object):
    def func(self, **kwargs):
        required = set(['arg1','arg2','arg3'])
        if not set(kwargs.keys()).issuperset(required):
            raise ArgException(kwargs)
```

although you could just let the interpreter take care of it:

```
class X(object):
    def func(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
```

Comment: +1 .. yes, see my comment to the question. I have no idea how I didn't know that..

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to allow other arguments? If not:

```
class X(object):
    def func(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
```

If yes:

```
class X(object):
    def func(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, **kwargs):
        pass
```

That's for all versions of Python.